# add function on a specific blog post - wordpress multsite

Tags: wordpress, function, post

Folks,

I have a wordpress multi sites.
I need to add a function where in only a specific blog it will add an iframe to the end of each post.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a hook to `the_content` function which is pretty straight forward. The problem you face is that you need it to only affect 1 of the blogs rather than all of them.

Luckily WordPress allows you to get the blog id with `get_current_blog_id()`. Using this you can identify which blog is which and only add your custom code if the appropriate blog is being used.

Add this to your functions.php file in your current theme. You'll need to figure out what the blog id is and modify the iframe code, but this should get you going:

```
function custom_content_hook($content) {
    if( get_current_blog_id() == INSERT_BLOG_ID ){
        $content .= '<iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="" height=""></iframe>';
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_hook' );
```

You can still use `the_content()` in your template files as you regularly would.

Answer (score 0):

The final code looked like this:

```
function custom_content_hook($content){

    $iframe = '<iframe src="#" frameborder="0" height="280px" width="620px"></iframe>';

    if( is_single() ){
        $content .= $iframe;
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_hook' );
```